# Не могу заставить работать скрипт, написанный на языке python. Написан он был 5 лет назад, так что возможно дело в версии языка

Tags: python, файловый-ввод-вывод

В этом языке вообще не разбираюсь, потыкался несколько часов по подсказкам компилятора, но так ничего и не получилось.

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# STL2H by Themistokle "mrt-prodz" Benetatos
# -------------------------------------------
# Convert STL 3D models (ASCII) to header for Tiny 3D Engine
# 
# ------------------------
# http://www.mrt-prodz.com
# http://github.com/mrt-prodz/ATmega328-Tiny-3D-Engine
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys, getopt, os

# global parameters
param_verbose = False
param_normals = False
param_yes     = False
param_scale   = 1.0

def checkFile(outfile):
    # keep asking user until overwrite is chosen or a non-existing file name is entered
    while (os.path.isfile(outfile) is True):
        overwrite = raw_input('[!] Output data file "%s" already exists, overwrite? [y/n] ' % outfile)
        if overwrite in ('y', 'Y'):
            return outfile
        elif overwrite in ('n', 'N'):
            outfile = raw_input('[?] Enter new output data file name: ')
            if (outfile == ''):
                outfile = 'temp.h'
    return outfile

def printVerbose(str):
    global param_verbose
    if param_verbose is True:
        print str,

def saveDAT(nodes, triangles, outfile, normals = None):
    print '[+] Saving output file:', outfile
    data  = '// exported with stl2h\n'
    data += '// '
    data += ' '.join(sys.argv[:]) + '\n'
    data += '#ifndef MESH_H\n'
    data += '#define MESH_H\n'
    data += '\n'
    data += '#define NODECOUNT ' + str(len(nodes)) + '\n'
    data += '#define TRICOUNT ' + str(len(triangles)) + '\n'
    data += '\n'
    data += '#define NODE(a, b) (long)(pgm_read_dword(&nodes[a][b]))\n'
    data += '#define EDGE(a, b) pgm_read_byte(&faces[a][b])\n'
    data += '#define NORMAL(a, b) (long)(pgm_read_dword(&normals[a][b]))\n'
    data += '\n'
    data += 'const long nodes[NODECOUNT][3] PROGMEM = {\n'
    for index, node in enumerate(nodes):
        data += '  {(long)(' + str(round(float(node[0]), 5)*param_scale) + '*PRES), '\
             + '(long)(' + str(round(float(node[1]), 5)*param_scale) + '*PRES), '\
             + '(long)(' + str(round(float(node[2]), 5)*param_scale) + '*PRES)},\n'
    data += '};\n\n'
    data += 'const unsigned char faces[TRICOUNT][3] PROGMEM = {\n'
    for index, face in enumerate(triangles):
               data += '  {' + str(face[0]) + ', ' + str(face[1]) + ', ' + str(face[2]) + '},\n'
        data += '};\n\n'
    data += 'const long normals[TRICOUNT][3] PROGMEM = {\n'
    for index, normal in enumerate(normals):
        data += '  {(long)(' + str(round(float(normal[0]), 5)) + '*PRES), '\
             + '(long)(' + str(round(float(normal[1]), 5)) + '*PRES), '\
             + '(long)(' + str(round(float(normal[2]), 5)) + '*PRES)},\n'
    data += '};\n\n'
    data += '#endif // MESH_H\n'
    dat = open(outfile, 'w')
    dat.write(data)
    dat.close()
    printVerbose(data)


def parseSTL(infile, outfile):
    global param_verbose
    if param_verbose is True:
        print '[+] Parsing STL file with verbose output'
    # if -y is not set check for file being overwritten
    global param_yes
    if param_yes is False:
        outfile = checkFile(outfile)
        print '[+] Input STL file:', infile
        print '[+] Output header file:', outfile
    stl = open(infile, 'r')
    nodes = []
    unique_nodes = []
    triangles = [[]]
    normals = []
    global param_normals
    if param_normals is True:
            print '[+] Saving facet normals information'
    # store vertex into list first
    print('[+] Gathering vertices')
    for index, line in enumerate(stl):
        # split line into tokens and keep only vertices
        token = line.split()
        if (len(token) == 4) and (token[0] == 'vertex'):
            # store x y z into list
            nodes.append([token[1], token[2], token[3]])
            printVerbose('    ' + line)
    # quickly check that we have sets of 3 vertices for each triangle
    check = len(nodes) % 3
    print '[+] STL file check:', ('good' if check == 0 else 'bad')
    if check != 0:
        print '[!] Error with STL file, each triangle should be made of 3 vertices (missing %d vertex)' % (3 - check)
        sys.exit(2)
    # keep only unique nodes
    print('[+] Keeping unique vertices')
    [unique_nodes.append(item) for item in nodes if item not in unique_nodes]
    # output stored vertices
    if param_verbose is True:
        for node in unique_nodes:
            # print previous triangle created
            printVerbose('    ' + str(node[0]) + ', '
                        + str(node[1]) + ', '
                                + str(node[2]) + '\n')

    # seek start of file to get triangles
    stl.seek(0, 0)
    # assign vertex index to triangle list
    print('[+] Gathering triangles')
    index = 0
    for line in stl:
        # split line into tokens
        token = line.split()
        if (len(token) == 4) and (token[0] == 'vertex'):
            # compare current array to unique_nodes and set index in triangle
            for i, node in enumerate(unique_nodes):
                # if xyz match
                if [token[1], token[2], token[3]] == node:
                    # add to current triangle list if array at index has less than 3 items
                    if len(triangles[index]) < 3:
                        triangles[index].append(i)
                        if len(triangles[index]) == 3:
                            # print previous triangle created
                            printVerbose('    ' + str(triangles[index][0]) + ', '
                                        + str(triangles[index][1]) + ', '
                                        + str(triangles[index][2]) + '\n')
                        break
                    # else create new array
                    else:
                        # increase index
                        index += 1
                        # append array with new item
                        triangles.append([i])
                        break

    # gather normals if parameter is true
    if param_normals is True:
        print('[+] Gathering normals')
        # seek start of file to get normals
        stl.seek(0, 0)
        # gather normals
        for line in stl:
            # split line into tokens
            token = line.split()
            if (len(token) == 5) and (token[0] == 'facet') and (token[1] == 'normal'):
                # store vector normal
                normal = [token[2], token[3], token[4]]
                # print normal if verbose mode
                printVerbose('    ' + str(normal[0]) + ', '
                            + str(normal[1]) + ', '
                            + str(normal[2]) + '\n')
                normals.append(normal)

    # print stats
    print '[+] Vertices: ', len(unique_nodes)
    print '[+] Triangles:', len(triangles)
    if param_normals is True:
        print '[+] Normals:', len(normals)
        saveDAT(unique_nodes, triangles, outfile, normals)
    else:
        saveDAT(unique_nodes, triangles, outfile, normals)
    print '[+] Done\n'

def usage():
    print 'Usage: %s -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>' % sys.argv[0]
    print 'Convert a 3D mesh saved as STL format (ASCII) to header for Tiny 3D Engine.\n'
    print '  -i, --inputfile \t3D mesh in STL file format'
    print '  -o, --outputfile\toutput filename of converted data'
    print '  -s, --scale     \tscale ratio (default 1.0)'
    print '  -n, --normals   \tsave face normals'
    print '  -y, --yes       \tanswer yes to all requests'
    print '  -v, --verbose   \tverbose output'

def main(argv):
    infile = ''
    outfile = ''
    # parse command line arguments
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'i:o:s:nhyv',['help', 'yes', 'normals', 'scale=', 'input=', 'output=', 'verbose='])
    except getopt.GetoptError as error:
        print 'Error:', str(error)
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
    if len(opts) < 2:
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
            usage()
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ('-i', '--input'):
            infile = arg
        elif opt in ('-o', '--output'):
            outfile = arg
        elif opt in ('-s', '--scale'):
            global param_scale
            try:
                param_scale = float(arg)
            except Exception as converror:
                print 'Error:', str(converror)
                sys.exit(2)
        elif opt in ('-v', '--verbose'):
            global param_verbose
            param_verbose = True
        elif opt in ('-y', '--yes'):
            global param_yes
            param_yes = True
        elif opt in ('-n', '--normals'):
            global param_normals
            param_normals = True
    if (not infile) or (not outfile):
        print 'Error: You need to specify both input and output files'
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
    if infile == outfile:
        print 'Error: Input and output files are the same'
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
    # parse STL file and convert to data
    parseSTL(infile, outfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: А почему не скачаете подходящую версию чтобы его запустить? Чтобы прям точно убрать версию с версией языка.

Comment: Не знаю, какую именно.

Comment: Какая ошибка возникает? На какой версии пробовали? Навскидку это `Python 2.x.x`. На ветке `3.x.x` точно не запустится.

Comment: Ругается на синтаксис у «‎print». Завтра попробую 2.х.х, спасибо ‎

Comment: @LTVA в python3.x print - это функция, а не оператор, потому вместо `print a, b, c` используется `print(a, b, c)`. А вообще, решение запускать код на python2.x более корректное`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте запустить через python2.7, в python3.* используются print как функции, это первое что бросилось в глаза, сидеть и вычленять все такие мелочи не хочется, проще поставить питон 2